# Where to find a follower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I need a follower but can't find one anywhere.

Comment: To the second part of your question, it depends on your playstyle. If you like to sneak in, then don't bother. If you like to charge in, then a follower with heavy armor can be great at tanking damage like an idiot when you need to run and heal.

Answer (score 5):

[Here's a list of all followers in the game](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers).

The first follower you get access to will likely be either Sven or Faendal in Riverwood, talk to either of them to do a simple quest that will net you a starter follower.